# Get-ADUser Filter on WhenCreated works for -lt but not -gt

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to search for users created after a specified date, but it always returns no results. If I change the **-gt/ge to -lt/le** it pulls results correctly, so this should be doable.  I know I can just filter for all and then do a Where-Object to filter for gt/ge but I really need the filter to happen server side.

Any ideas on how to make this successful without doing Where-Object or using the Get-QADUser?

Update 2015.01.23:  Not always getting this error, but it help point to the issue:  Get-ADUser : This operation returned because the timeout period expired

```
$Today = Get-Date -year (Get-Date).Year -Month (Get-Date).Month -Day (Get-Date).Day -Hour 00 -Minute 00 -Second 00

$StartDate = $Today.AddDays(-3)

$inputProperties = @(
"samaccountname"
"employeeid"
"title"
"enabled"
"manager"
"whencreated"
)


Get-ADUser -Filter {(whencreated -ge $StartDate)} -Properties $inputProperties
```

Comment: if the -lt/le works can you not combine it with the -not operator which is supported in the filter syntax to achieve a -gt/ge?

Comment: tested, working fine for me, *btw you can change the `$today` to: `$Today = Get-Date 00:00:00`

Comment: Thanks @Avshalom for the Get-Date 00:00:00.

This still does not return any results.  I have gotten it to display a time out error a few times, so that may be the issue.

    Get-ADUser : This operation returned because the timeout period expired

Comment: @DanL I tried this as well but same results

Comment: Have you tried `get-help about_ActiveDirectory_Filter` and under TimeOut Behavior: The default Active Directory module timeout for all operations is 2 minutes.  Then review the options given to improve your filters performance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code as well and it worked fine. Also, you can change the variable `$Today` to `$Today = (Get-Date).date` and it gets the same results. If you're getting a timeout error maybe try saving the list of users with the properties listed into a variable and then filtering on that?

```
$Today = (Get-Date).date

$StartDate = $Today.AddDays(-3)

$inputProperties = @(
"samaccountname"
"employeeid"
"title"
"enabled"
"manager"
"whencreated"
)


$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter {(whencreated -ge $StartDate)} -Properties $inputProperties

$Users | ? { $_.whencreated -ge $StartDate }
```

If that still fails, try setting the `ResultSetSize` parameter. If you still get a timeout error then you know there's another issue on hand.

```
Get-ADUser -ResultSetSize 1 -Filter {(whencreated -ge $StartDate)} -Properties $inputProperties
```

EDIT: holy crap, didn't realize this post was 7 years old. I'll leave my answer up in case it helps someone who stumbles upon this question.