# Get-ADUser with whenCreated in filter

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm looking to find AD user accounts created between two timestamps. However, I'm facing this redundant issue of not being able to fetch AD user objects with `Get-ADUser` while using the `whenCreated` attribute along with `-gt` or `-ge` or `-lt` **(excepting `-le`)** in `-Filter` or `-LDAPFilter` parameters of the cmdlet. The cmdlet just works fine and starts returning AD user objects immediately when using the `-le` operator only.

Below is a snapshot of errors when tried with `-LDAPFilter` with `-ge`, `-lt`, `-gt` in order,

[image: get-aduser-w-whenCreated-not-working-w-gt-ge-lt]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941610/get-aduser-filter-on-whencreated-works-for-lt-but-not-gt) seems to be a related post. However, I find no working solution there, and when tried using the `!` (the not operator) with `-le` *(to bring `-gt` into effect)*, I still received a timeout exception. I've also tried to reduce the `-ResultPageSize` value to 5, still no luck - the timeout error is thrown.

[image: get-aduser-w-whenCreated-gt-from-not-le]

I'd like to filter on the server-side as the directory is huge and retrieving all objects and then filtering on the client-side would not be very much efficient.
Any suggestions or workaround is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell conveniently converts the `whenCreated` attribute from the [GeneralizedTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/s-string-generalized-time) format in UTC to a Local DateTime using property `Created`.

I cannot test this at the moment, but any of these should work:

```
# define the start and end dates (Local time)
$startDate = (Get-Date -Year 2021 -Month 1 -Day 14).Date  # discard the time part, so set to midnight
$endDate   = (Get-Date).Date
```

try:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Created -gt $startDate -and Created -le $endDate'
```

or filter afterwards using a `Where-Object` clause:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Created | Where-Object { $_.Created -gt $startDate -and $_.Created -le $endDate }
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you very much, Theo! This has helped me a great deal. +1

Comment: Bizarrely it works with single quotes but not double quotes `'whencreated -ge $date'`

Comment: @js2010 Yes, that is strange indeed, but lately I understood that the `-Filter` for Get-ADUser is **always** forcibly converted to string before the cmdlet's PowerShell provider interprets that string and translates it to LDAP syntax. Especially on DateTime objects this provides the weird/unexpected behavior where sometimes it works and sometimes it fails. I have not tested yet, but `"Created -ge '$date'"` should also work. I have now updated my answer so the first option uses single-quotes.

Comment: Doublequotes do not work.  It seems like the single quoted version sends the datetime in for conversion to generalizedtime, but double quote sends in a string?

Comment: Theo: the reason why single quotes work is because the datetime instance is passed as is to the AD Filter provider which does the datetime conversion for you. As opposed, double quotes result in the interpolation of the instance in the string before it (the filter) being passed to the provider.

Answer (score 2):

Code example, if you want to bother converting to the Generalized-time that active directory uses for the whencreated property on the backend.

```
$date = get-date '1/2/2022 1am' | % touniversaltime | 
  get-date -format yyyyMMddHHmmss.0Z

$date
20220102060000.0Z

get-aduser -filter “whencreated -ge '$date'” -property whencreated -ResultSetSize 5 | 
  select name,whencreated

name   whencreated
----   -----------
lp1076 1/3/2022 8:14:16 AM
jt600  1/3/2022 8:59:41 AM
ec737  1/3/2022 9:05:50 AM
db663  1/3/2022 9:08:58 AM
zw     1/3/2022 10:12:07 AM
```

Bizarrely, single-quotes work with a datetime object in this case, but double-quotes do not.

```
$date = get-date '1/2/2022 1am'
get-aduser -filter 'whencreated -ge $date' 
# get-aduser -filter "whencreated -ge '$date'"
```

Comment: yes single quotes work because the datetime instance is passed to the AD Provider and the AD Provider does the datetime conversion for you.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon You would think a single quoted variable would just be a literal dollar sign and letters, but that's the black magic of ad filters...

Comment: yep. using `'...'` is the same as using a scriptblock in the filter which sometimes works like in this case and facilitates a lot with date conversion but fails many other times. this function helps seeing how filters are translated in LDAP Syntax by the AD Provider: https://gist.github.com/santisq/330664422f88c49fb79bf0e778ac74a2