# I am trying to get-adgroupmember from ad groups created in the last 30 days:

Tags: powershell-3.0

```
$groups = "TWA_NDL_ObsApp_WR_MAN", "TWA_NDL_ObsApp_WR", "TWA_NDL_ObsApp_WH_MAN"

$users = Get-ADUser -Filter "(whenCreated -ge '$((Get-Date).AddDays(-30))')" -Properties whenCreated, memberOf |
  Where-Object {$_.memberOf -like $groups} | 
  Select-Object Name, whenCreated, @{Name="Groups";Expression={$_.memberOf -join '; '}} | 
  Sort-Object whenCreated |
  Export-Csv -Path "C:\Scripts\gmembers.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

new group members created in the last 30 days

Comment: whencreated is in generalizedtime format behind the scenes.  created is easier to deal with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65746553/get-aduser-with-whencreated-in-filter