boolean values not evaluating properly
In the last statement with the where-object clause, it doesn't seem to be picking up on the "enabled" field every time. Users are pulled from AD and grouped by the value of 'o' attribute. The grouped values for each row should then be counted to give totals for the 'enabled' and 'new' attributes. At first, it seemed it worked properly until I looked at the results more closely. The count for 'enabled' isn't always accurate so when I looked at a smaller subset of users hat I could manually verify, it's not counting all true values.
﻿$filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))"
$params = @{
    "Properties" = 
    "userprincipalname", "whenCreated","physicaldeliveryofficename","o"
}

$adPath = "OU=Users,DC=site,DC=org,"


$now=Get-Date
$endDate = Get-Date -Day 15 -Month $now.Month -Year $now.Year -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0
$startDate = $endDate.addMonths(-1)



$users = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $filter -SearchBase $adPath @params 

$orgs = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]

$g = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$u = [System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]]::New()

$users | ForEach-Object {
        
    $n = $false
    if ($_.whenCreated -ne $null -and $_.whenCreated -ge $startDate -and $_.whenCreated -le $endDate){
        $n = $true
    }

    $x = [pscustomobject]@{
        enabled =  [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($_.Enabled)
        o=[String]$_.o
        new = $n
     }

    $u.Add($x)

}



$u | Group o | Sort count -Descending | Select Name, @{Name='Enabled';Expression={($_.Group | Where-Object [String]enabled -eq 'True').Count}}, @{Name='New';Expression={($_.Group | Where-Object new -eq $true).Count}}, @{Name='Total';Expression={$_.Count}}, Group

For example, when I pull from an OU with only 2 users in it, my output looks like this:

Name    : ABCD
Enabled : 
Total   : 2
Group   : {@{enabled=True; o=ABCD; new=False}, @{enabled=False; o=ABCD; new=False}}

In this case, I don't even get a 0 for Enabled, as if the result is just null.  If I change the WHERE condition to this:
[String]Enabled -eq 'True'

Then the count gives 0, but still not accurate as it should be 1.  On other groups, Enabled does return a count value that appears close to what I expect, but it would be difficult to manually verify as those contain hundreds of users.  I'm at a loss at this point why the value is counted sometimes and not others. Maybe something to do with the conversion/casting of the value out of AD?

You want @($_.Group |Where-Object Enabled -eq $true).Count

ah ok that makes sense, that tells it its an array right?. So without the @ what was it counting? Because I did have larger groups with high count results.

You probably want to use created instead of whencreated, which is in generalizedtime internally.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65746553/get-aduser-with-whencreated-in-filter .  Enabled is already boolean.

The @ doesn't matter.  The problem is Where-Object [String]enabled -eq 'True'

I assume the comma at the end of $adpath is a typo.  I'm not familiar with an "o" property.

@js2010 o is the LDAP property for Organization

@theo my AD doesn't have it

@js2010: @(...) also matters: the intrinsic .Count property isn't available on a single ADUser instance, so in order to ensure that .Count always works, you need @(...)

@mklement0 (1).count works for me.

@js2010: it works for me too, as noted in my answer ((42).Count). 1 is an instance of [int], not of [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser]. How the two types differ with respect to using the intrinsic .Count property is spelled out in my answer.

@mklement0 no difference

@js2010, I don't have access to AD anymore; my analysis is based on potentially obsolete behavior, but the behavior with respect to AD objects, specifically, is ultimately irrelevant: The point is that (...).Count doesn't reliably provide the count of objects emitted by the pipeline represented by ..., whereas @(...) does (as explained in my answer). Try (Write-Output @{ Count = 'psych!' }).Count vs. @(Write-Output @{ Count = 'psych!' }).Count

@mklement0 If you actually run the code, a count of one works.

@js2010: I assume your comment was posted before you had a chance to read my previous one, which was posted just seconds before yours. If the commands in in my previous comment behave differently for you, I'd be (a) very surprised and (b) would want to know how our environments differ - I see the same behavior in Windows PowerShell and PowerShell 7.4.1

@mklement0 My bad.  0 or 2 pscustomobjects have a count inside parentheses, but 1 doesn't.  A groupinfo object has a count property.

Thanks, @js2010; the single-[pscustomobject] issue affects WinPS, but was fixed in PS 7 (([pscustomobject] @{ }).Count now properly reports 1).


tl;dr
Replace:
($_.Group | Where-Object [String]enabled -eq 'True').Count

with:
@($_.Group | Where-Object Enabled).Count


Where-Object [String]enabled -eq 'True' doesn't work as intended; it is the equivalent of Where-Object { ($_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty '[String]enabled') -eq 'True' }

Don't use string comparisons with [bool] (Boolean values), rely on PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean conversion.

To reliably count the number of objects emitted by a pipeline, enclose the pipeline in @(...)


Read on for details.


# !! BROKEN
($_.Group | Where-Object [String]enabled -eq 'True').Count

doesn't work as you expect it to: you cannot use casts such as [string] in the context of using simplified syntax.
Your Where-Object call is equivalent to the following, which makes the problem obvious:
# !! NEVER produces output, because the filter is *always $false*.
Where-Object { ($_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty '[String]enabled') -eq 'True' }

In the simplified-syntax command, bareword [String]enabled was (positionally) bound to Where-Object's -Property parameter.
-Property interprets [String]enabled as a wildcard pattern, as demonstrated in js2010's answer, with character-set expression [String] matching a single character that is (case-insensitively) one of: s t r i n g, and, obviously, no property named senabled or tenabled or ... is present.
Omitting the broken attempt at a cast would work, if you also specify a [bool] as the RHS -eq operand:
# Works, but is unnecessary.
Where-Object Enabled -eq $true

Specifying only a -Property argument, without an operation, implicitly treats the property value as a [bool] - see the conceptual about_Booleans help topic; thus, you can simplify to:
# Same as:
#   Where-Object { [bool] $_.Enabled -eq $true }
# and therefore:
#   Where-Object { [bool] $_.Enabled }
Where-Object Enabled


While you generally need not also enclose the pipeline in @(...), the array-subexpression operator before applying the .Count property, it is the safe thing to do if you want to count objects emitted by a pipeline:

The pipeline can emit an open-ended number of objects, and it is only two or more output objects that (of necessity) result in an array when the objects are captured, such as via (...), the grouping operator

In other words: If a pipeline happens to emit just one object, that object is captured as-is, whereas two or more objects are collect in an array ([object[]]).


To make it easier to work with this situationally varying output, i.e. to unify the handling of scalars (single objects) and arrays (enumerables), v3 of PowerShell introduced intrinsic members that allow you to treat even a single object as if it were a single-element array; the intrinsic .Count property and its .Length alias that PowerShell provides is 1 for a single (non-collection) object, and indices [0] and [-1] return the object itself; e.g.:
# OK: -> 2 
(Write-Output 42, 43).Count 

# OK too: -> 1, due to the intrinsic .Count property
# Same as: (42).Count
(Write-Output 42).Count 

# OK: -> 42
# Ditt for: (42)[-1]
(42)[0] 


However, there are scenarios in which these intrinsic properties are NOT available:

If a given single object itself has type-native members of that name, as the following example demonstrates:
 # !! -> 'psych!'
 # Since the [pscustomobject] instance itself has a .Count property,
 # *it* is used.
 (Write-Output ([pscustomobject] @{ Count = 'psych!' })).Count


If a given single object is of type that implements the IDynamicMetaObjectProvider interface, such as System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject:
$expandoObject = [System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject]::new()
$expandoObject.Foo = 'bar'
$expandoObject.Count = 'psych!'

# !! -> 'psych!'
# Since the object instance itself has a (dynamic) .Count property,
# *it* is used.
($expandoObject).Count


Note that, due to bug reported in GitHub issue #15204, outputting an ExpandoObject instance via the pipeline in effect makes .Count report the number of dynamic properties instead; e.g., (Write-Output $expandoObject).Count is 2 rather than the expected 'psych!', because use in the pipeline unexpectedly results in the enumeration of the dynamic properties of the single object, as [System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[string, object]] instances.


De facto, as your output implies, the objects emitted by the Active Directory provider, such as via Get-ADUser, also make the intrinsic properties unavailable:

When .Count is used on a single instance, an empty collection of type ADPropertyCollection is returned, which makes it appear as if nothing was returned.

That an empty collection would be returned for a nonexistent property, rather than $null, as in the case of IDynamicMetaObjectProvider, is questionable.

ADPropertyCollection type is the base class for all objects emitted by the AD Provider; however, it does not implement IDynamicMetaObjectProvider, though it behaves similarly in PowerShell: collection members are presented as if they were distinct properties, which is an example of a type adapter (adapted properties) provided by PowerShell's ETS (Extended Type System) - see this blog post for background information.







This doesn't give an error, but it doesn't work as intended with the "[String]".  I would stick with $true since get-aduser returns a boolean type for the enabled property.
[pscustomobject]@{enabled = $true} | Where-Object [String]enabled -eq $true
# no result

Hah, looks like [String] is treated as a wildcard pattern:
[pscustomobject]@{Senabled = $true} | Where-Object [String]enabled -eq $true

Senabled
--------
    True


[pscustomobject]@{tenabled = $true} | Where-Object [String]enabled -eq $true

tenabled
--------
    True

